# Sticky div, problem once the div reach the footer

Tags: html, css

I have created a div #barrabooking (inside of that there is a reservation form) that stick on the bottom of the screen.
The problem is that once the div reach the footer it cover some of the content that are at the end the footer.

You can see live here: https://www.visitmontaione.com/wcomm/it/montaione-toscana-italia/

I have used this code:

```
#barrabookingfor{
    padding: 0 220px;
    font: normal normal 1.0em 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    z-index: 1;
}

.sticky {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 9999;
}
```

Than in the template, I use

```
<!-- START Sticky menu -->      
    <script>
            window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

            var navbar = document.getElementById("barrabookingfor");
            var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

            function myFunction() {
              if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
                navbar.classList.add("sticky")
              } else {
                navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
              }
            }
    </script>
<!-- END Sticky menu -->
```

How can I make the div #barrabooking let the page scroll completely withou covering the last part?

Many thanks

Filippo

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

You can give the copyright div a defined height and remove the `display:table` class

```
#barra-copyright {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #4d6a79;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 327px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works, but I am not able to make it works when responsive with screen smaller than 768px.
How can I do? Thanks.

Comment: You could use a custom media query to set the height of the div at different breakpoints. `@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {#barra-copyright {height: 700px; }}`